# Como fazer consulta com filtro no Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Estou começando no Firebase e gostaria de saber como fazer consulta com filtro, exemplo:

Selecionar, apenas pessoas que moram em Porto Alegre.

Hoje, o que tenho é uma estrutura de BD.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho 4 tabelas, rua, bairro, cidade e estado.
A primeira que postei é a tabela é estado, a outra é rua/logradouro.

Comment: Isso vai depender completamente de como os dados estão dispostos. Coloque um exemplo de como está a sua árvore de dados.

Comment: Desculpe Pablo, mas ainda não fiz a estrutura.
Só tenho minha estrutura em SQL.

Comment: Ah, entendi. Então... o Firebase, como você deve saber, é NoSQL, e possui os dados estruturados em forma de JSON (mais ou menos). Diferente de um banco de dados SQL, no qual trabalhamos em um nível mais abstrato, no Firebase você decide exatamente onde fica cada elemento. Você vai ter que organizar os dados no Firebase de forma a ficar mais fácil pra fazer esse filtro, mas é meio que na mão. Um bom exercício talvez seja tentar criar um JSON offline e ler a partir dele. Como faria? Se você segue a boa prática de ter uma abstração (padrão Repository, por exemplo), faça uma implementação com JSON

Comment: Ir para o Firebase depois vai ser só questão de mais alguns ajustes.

Comment: Sim Pablo, to ligado que o Firebase é NoSQL e sim estruturado da forma JSON.
Você sugere eu montar a estrutura, direto nele e tentar fazer as consultas?

Comment: Pode ser direto nele ou num JSON no seu computador mesmo (ou até XML). O importante é pegar as informações que estão no seu esquema atual e dispô-las de forma hierárquica. Uma vez feito isso, vai ficar claro como fazer a consulta filtrando como você precisar.

Comment: Pois é, eu tentei fazer na mão, direto lá, mas só consegui criar dados na raiz, como, nome e valor, vários, um abaixo do outro e só, não consegui colocar os filhos.

Comment: Clique no "+" pra criar um novo filho.

Comment: Sim, isso eu sei, mas digo, pra fazer consulta como com where do sql @PabloAlmeida.

Comment: Eu acho que essa página aqui vai lhe ajudar. Eu também estou vindo do mySQL e esse conceito de noSQL pra mim ainda é estranho.
[Querying lists](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md)

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Pois, noSQL é um bocado assustador para quem vem do mySQL. Mas existe esta série de artigos em português que pode ajudar muito: https://medium.com/android-dev-moz/firebasesql-4ee3d26a3d15#.h6w3goky4

Comment: É possível converter sua estrutura para o Firebase facilmente. O que tem que ficar claro é que não existe um "where" no Firebase, mas sim um filtro nas referências. Se quiser, seguindo seu exemplo, consultar todas as pessoas que moram você tem que pegar a referência e usar um equalTo no child. Mas por experiência, junte estas tabelas em uma somente, mesmo que se repitam os campos. Facilita depois na hora das consultas. Inclua endereço, cidade, estado, etc tudo na tabela pessoa.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase usa uma estrutura de JSON-tree, no seu caso, você poderia criar um 'filho' chamado pessoas, listando todas as pessoas do seu sistema. Cada pessoa seria um nó com filhos contento suas características.

```
firebase
   -pessoas
       -uid1
           -nome:"USER 1"
           -UF:"RS"
       -uid2
           -nome:"USER 2"
           -UF:"RS"
       -uid3
           -nome:"USER 3"
           -UF:"SC"
```

Na sua busca, você pode usar "equalTo()" e filtra pelo "filho" especifico, nesse caso você poderia buscar todas pessoas com o filho "UF" **equalTo()** 'RS'

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data

Answer (score -2):

O Firebase **NÃO** funciona como um Sistema Gerenciador de Banco de Dados SQL. Uma das principais diferenças é que o Firebase foca em distribuir dados diretos e não em filtrar (*where*) e juntar dados distintos (*join*). Isso significa que, se você for cuidadoso o suficiente, aprender como o Firebase funciona e modelar os seus dados seguindo a lógica do Firebase, você não precisa de um servidor dedicado para *queries* simples pois elas são feitas direto no dispositivo do cliente.

Para mais informações, assista a playlist do David East sobre **O Banco de Dados Firebase Para Desenvolvedores SQL**, disponível em https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s.

Comment: Pois é! E para quem não entende muito inglês, pode ler esta série de artigos em português :) https://medium.com/android-dev-moz/firebasesql-4ee3d26a3d15#.h6w3goky4

Comment: Acredito que não ajuda na resposta, pois é possível sim fazer um filtro do jeito que foi perguntado. Pelos comentarios da pergunta ele sabe que realmente é NoSQL o Firebase, mas ele gostaria de saber se há uma equivalência na consulta e como fazer. No caso este [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) resolve a questão.

Comment: Não seria melhor colocar um exemplo de como pegar os documentos que tem o valor "Porto Alegre" no campo cidade? Pois esta explicação não ajudou em nada